# Interception of browser's requests (post/get)

Tags: java, tomcat

i'm looking for a way to write a programm wich should intercept all browser's post and get requests.
The program should filter these requests and search for some resources. I want to forbit access to these resources.
It should be a kind of parental control.
I have:

- apache tomcad;
- java.

P.S. Sorry for my english, i know it's not perfect=)

Thanks.

Remark: the program should be a desktop appleication.

Comment: Use [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)?

Comment: A filter is probably correct way to go, but be careful with performance if you're filter does a search on every request.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html). Here a short description about it.

> A filter is an object that performs filtering tasks on either the request to a resource (a servlet or static content), or on the response from a resource, or both.

Examples that have been identified for this design are:

- Authentication Filters
- Logging and Auditing Filters
- Image conversion Filters
- Data compression Filters
- Encryption Filters
- Tokenizing Filters
- Filters that trigger resource access events
- XSL/T filters
- Mime-type chain Filter

---

Sample code:

web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.x.y.z.servlet.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

MyFilter.java:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {


    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        // read init-parameter from web.xml
    }


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        String uri = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();


        // do what you want to do based on uri

        // call below method to propagate it to next servet/jsp/filter in the chain
        // filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);

    }    

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```